# metpy divergence module array indexing error

Tags: python, data-analysis, calculation, atmosphere, metpy

I am trying to find out moisture divergence using `metpy` divergence module .Now I am doing it for a dictionary with years being the keys,

```
HMD = {}

    for year in [2012, 2018, 2019]:
        # Get the resampled dataset for the current year
        resampled_ds = resampled_data[year]
        # Slice latitude and longitude ranges
        # Select latitude values within the desired range(8-12, 75-77)
        lat_range = resampled_ds['latitude'].where((resampled_ds['latitude'] >= 8) & (resampled_ds['latitude'] <= 12), drop=True)
        sliced_ds = resampled_ds.sel(latitude=lat_range, longitude=slice(75, 78))
        # Calculate the moisture flux components
        qu_l = (sliced_ds['Q'] * sliced_ds['U'])
        qv_l = (sliced_ds['Q'] * sliced_ds['V'])
        # Compute the grid deltas (dx, dy) in meters
        dx, dy = mpcalc.lat_lon_grid_deltas(sliced_ds['longitude'], sliced_ds['latitude'])
        # Compute the divergence of the moisture flux
        HMD[year] = mpcalc.divergence(qu_l, qv_l, dx=dx, dy=dy)
        HMD[year] = HMD
```

Now I am getting the error as

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    
      Cell In[35], line 17
        HMD[year] = mpcalc.divergence(qu_l, qv_l, dx=dx, dy=dy)
    
      File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/metpy/calc/tools.py:1178 in wrapper
        return func(*bound_args.args, **bound_args.kwargs)
    
      File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/metpy/xarray.py:1329 in wrapper
        result = func(*bound_args.args, **bound_args.kwargs)
    
      File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/metpy/units.py:332 in wrapper
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    
      File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/metpy/calc/kinematics.py:159 in divergence
        dudx, dvdy = vector_derivative(
    
      File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/metpy/calc/tools.py:1178 in wrapper
        return func(*bound_args.args, **bound_args.kwargs)
    
      File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/metpy/xarray.py:1329 in wrapper
        result = func(*bound_args.args, **bound_args.kwargs)
    
      File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/metpy/units.py:332 in wrapper
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    
      File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/metpy/calc/tools.py:1571 in vector_derivative
        derivatives[component] = first_derivative(scalar, delta=delta, axis=dim)
    
      File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/metpy/calc/tools.py:951 in wrapper
        return preprocess_and_wrap()(func)(f, **kwargs)
    
      File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/metpy/xarray.py:1329 in wrapper
        result = func(*bound_args.args, **bound_args.kwargs)
    
      File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/metpy/calc/tools.py:1248 in first_derivative
        combined_delta = delta[delta_slice0] + delta[delta_slice1]
    
      File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pint/facets/numpy/quantity.py:253 in __getitem__
        return type(self)(self._magnitude[key], self._units)
    
    IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 2-dimensional, but 4 were indexed
```

here  `qu_l` and `qv_l` are 4D `xarrays(lon,lat,level,time)I am displaying the format of qu_l below

```
<xarray.DataArray (time: 122, level: 20, latitude: 17, longitude: 13)>
array([[[[-4.19789273e-03, -4.12086723e-03, -4.09764051e-03, ...,
          -3.71682970e-03, -3.73217138e-03, -3.82781331e-03],
         [-4.56113275e-03, -4.45598038e-03, -4.42688400e-03, ...,
          -3.76262050e-03, -3.75747494e-03, -3.89366969e-03],
         [-4.71409503e-03, -4.65912791e-03, -4.63059498e-03, ...,
          -3.87056964e-03, -3.85122397e-03, -3.96054145e-03],
         ...,
         [-4.45869751e-03, -4.44581639e-03, -4.42417897e-03, ...,
          -3.94128077e-03, -3.80358030e-03, -3.72603862e-03],
         [-4.08468908e-03, -4.09023836e-03, -4.06995276e-03, ...,
          -3.74964159e-03, -3.62544949e-03, -3.51385027e-03],
         [-3.59571190e-03, -3.61532927e-03, -3.61628691e-03, ...,
          -3.30728292e-03, -3.25384876e-03, -3.16099427e-03]],

        [[-3.50524322e-03, -3.57510871e-03, -3.70393903e-03, ...,
          -5.11942152e-03, -5.17477514e-03, -5.19334339e-03],
         [-3.62999109e-03, -3.61768738e-03, -3.63567495e-03, ...,
          -4.97422507e-03, -4.89413133e-03, -4.91650915e-03],
         [-3.82309570e-03, -3.69889149e-03, -3.64601682e-03, ...,
          -5.00734057e-03, -4.79878346e-03, -4.74505918e-03],
...
           6.10205606e-02,  8.29948708e-02,  9.58984271e-02],
         [ 1.19615391e-01,  1.20305233e-01,  1.18257053e-01, ...,
           1.16345897e-01,  1.31085232e-01,  1.47202030e-01],
         [ 1.19616143e-01,  1.20933101e-01,  1.21104434e-01, ...,
           1.74180165e-01,  1.87850669e-01,  1.94131300e-01]],

        [[ 5.08086272e-02,  2.28128675e-02,  1.50085404e-03, ...,
           1.51794543e-02,  1.48344487e-02,  1.89040005e-02],
         [ 6.45153522e-02,  4.22009490e-02,  1.40351783e-02, ...,
           9.95836034e-03,  1.04583772e-02,  1.45543003e-02],
         [ 7.31716752e-02,  5.91978468e-02,  3.37371565e-02, ...,
           2.09518019e-02,  2.17951648e-02,  2.08518244e-02],
         ...,
         [ 1.16454110e-01,  1.15208797e-01,  1.13529585e-01, ...,
           3.19227539e-02,  4.88603711e-02,  7.77506232e-02],
         [ 1.16338752e-01,  1.16264150e-01,  1.15892082e-01, ...,
           7.18823373e-02,  9.30104330e-02,  1.29432485e-01],
         [ 1.16498962e-01,  1.16809532e-01,  1.18171051e-01, ...,
           1.51875705e-01,  1.67853177e-01,  1.79388359e-01]]]],
      dtype=float32)
Coordinates:
  * longitude  (longitude) float64 75.0 75.25 75.5 75.75 ... 77.5 77.75 78.0
  * latitude   (latitude) float64 12.0 11.75 11.5 11.25 ... 8.75 8.5 8.25 8.0
  * level      (level) float64 300.0 350.0 400.0 450.0 ... 950.0 975.0 1e+03
  * time       (time) datetime64[ns] 2012-06-01 2012-06-02 ... 2012-09-30
```

qv_l below

```
<xarray.DataArray (time: 122, level: 20, latitude: 17, longitude: 13)>
array([[[[-6.47565699e-04, -6.92666334e-04, -7.11454137e-04, ...,
           3.43675456e-05,  7.93513536e-05,  9.99554468e-05],
         [-5.98114333e-04, -6.92268950e-04, -7.08624371e-04, ...,
           2.13778058e-05,  9.44525091e-05,  1.06804677e-04],
         [-4.73025109e-04, -5.89269039e-04, -6.22700143e-04, ...,
           6.42042323e-06,  4.46782178e-05,  5.74382866e-05],
         ...,
         [ 3.80350364e-04,  2.62222486e-04,  1.71314430e-04, ...,
           4.27812301e-06, -2.65385243e-05, -1.54171885e-05],
         [ 4.22323850e-04,  2.98410363e-04,  2.13784966e-04, ...,
           1.68663741e-04,  1.84557546e-04,  1.97871675e-04],
         [ 5.13842097e-04,  3.87011911e-04,  2.92879849e-04, ...,
           3.24941822e-04,  3.70173249e-04,  3.82417551e-04]],

        [[ 1.75689324e-03,  1.64970604e-03,  1.64240529e-03, ...,
           1.78657123e-03,  1.64312439e-03,  1.71366835e-03],
         [ 1.96785224e-03,  1.73268584e-03,  1.63920829e-03, ...,
           1.81653339e-03,  1.52228458e-03,  1.59630203e-03],
         [ 2.24626926e-03,  1.97174773e-03,  1.82870147e-03, ...,
           1.90237688e-03,  1.56884897e-03,  1.52667740e-03],
...
           4.07637330e-03,  1.11457016e-02,  3.93296406e-02],
         [-2.15423908e-02, -2.25263517e-02, -2.33091526e-02, ...,
          -9.87390056e-03,  1.77768152e-02,  5.02842739e-02],
         [-2.38218643e-02, -2.46686693e-02, -2.55033616e-02, ...,
          -2.89178826e-02,  6.09542197e-03,  3.83579805e-02]],

        [[ 2.17485931e-02,  3.29152979e-02,  2.30377540e-02, ...,
          -6.61660591e-03, -1.07659819e-03,  7.52496673e-03],
         [ 1.48354117e-02,  3.08191925e-02,  3.08241658e-02, ...,
           8.02161754e-04,  4.64674085e-03,  7.84640480e-03],
         [ 8.24724324e-03,  2.21066289e-02,  3.19518633e-02, ...,
           1.44633185e-02,  1.17855463e-02,  7.52754183e-03],
         ...,
         [-1.78987961e-02, -1.84495021e-02, -1.84885692e-02, ...,
           2.53087748e-03,  1.50247170e-02,  4.98900302e-02],
         [-2.08280329e-02, -2.19783485e-02, -2.26367787e-02, ...,
          -3.64710577e-03,  2.76481360e-02,  6.56655282e-02],
         [-2.32993308e-02, -2.39235573e-02, -2.48144343e-02, ...,
          -2.18581613e-02,  1.57092009e-02,  4.94669676e-02]]]],
      dtype=float32)
Coordinates:
  * longitude  (longitude) float64 75.0 75.25 75.5 75.75 ... 77.5 77.75 78.0
  * latitude   (latitude) float64 12.0 11.75 11.5 11.25 ... 8.75 8.5 8.25 8.0
  * level      (level) float64 300.0 350.0 400.0 450.0 ... 950.0 975.0 1e+03
  * time       (time) datetime64[ns] 2012-06-01 2012-06-02 ... 2012-09-30
```

Why this indexing error happens in metpy. Is it because metpy divergence module has any issue with 4darray
@Dopplershift, I tried both  your suggestions it is giving outputs but the values are wrong.

Comment: If you are passing in `DataArray`s with proper metadata, you shouldn't need to calcualte `dx` or `dy`. Can you please include the FULL error traceback as well as the output of `print(qu_l)` and `print(qv_l)`?

Comment: @DopplerShift  I have included the ful error traceback and the format of qu_l ad qv_l as per your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you're passing in `dx` and `dy` manually, which come from `lat_lon_grid_deltas()`. As a result, these are essentially regular numpy arrays and need to be compatible with `qu_l` and `qu_v` using standard numpy broadcasting rules. If you wanted these to work, you would need to add leading, size-1 dimensions to make these 2D arrays work with the 4D `qu_l` and `qv_l`, like:

```py
mpcalc.divergence(qu_l, qv_l, dx=dx[None, None], dy=dy[None, None])
```

Or most simply, since you already have data using xarray `DataArray` instances, don't calculate `dx`/`dy` manually, or pass them in at all. Instead, just MetPy can handle it for you:

```py
mpcalc.divergence(qu_l, qv_l)
```

Comment: I tried both of these and I am getting the same error  'too many indices for array: array is 2-dimensional, but 4 were indexed'

Comment: I tried locally with 4-dimensional data and it worked fine, so there's some detail about your data we're missing here. What data set is it? If it's not readily available somewhere, can you share the data files somewhere I can get them?

Comment: It is Era-5 reanalysis data.  whether it is the problem with dictionaries?

Comment: Dictionaries should be fine. It might be easier to continue this over at https://github.com/Unidata/MetPy/discussions where you can attach the full script you're using and the data file.

Comment: Sorry, I do't know how to ask questions in github. I created my account recently.

Comment: Apologies. I need some way to get to the data file to help any further. I have verified the function works as intended with 4D data, so there's something unique about this dataset that's creating the problem.